# NHibernate: Check referenced entity only if it's not null

Tags: nhibernate, reference, mapping, nullable, fluent

Tables:

- Name

  - id
  - datemodified
- NameLink

  - id
  - nameid
  - datemodified

Mapping for NameLink:

```
Id(p => p.Id, "id").GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
Map(p => p.DateModified, "datemodified");
References<Name>(p => p.Name, "nameid");
```

Name entry might be deleted from table. In my hql query i'm trying to check that Name is not null and only if it is - check it's datemodified. If Name is null i will check only NameLink's datemodified:

```
where ($it.Name is not null AND $it.Name.DateModified > 'xxx') OR ($it.DateModified > 'xxx')
```

If Name entry was deleted i get no results but i should. I have intercepted SQL.
I see that in WHERE clause the first check is "namelink.nameid = name.id". I believe it's because of Reference<> relationship.

Could someone please help me with modifying mapping?

**EDIT:** My GET query goes to WebAPI where we are transforming it to HQL. This query goes to BaseController so i can only modify query result only with OData possibilites because code is common for all other entity types. I get this kind of HQL query `from NameExternalLink $it where (($it.Name.DateModifiedUtc > '2015-03-31 11:29:45' OR $it.Name.DateCreatedUtc > '2015-03-31 11:29:45')) or ($it.DateModifiedUtc > '2015-03-31 11:29:45' OR $it.DateCreatedUtc > '2015-03-31 11:29:45')` But $it.Name might be null if corresponding row was deleted. If corresponding name exists query is working perfectly but if it wad deleted this row is just skipped. I think it's skipped because Name is mapped by "References" relation and when hql is transformed to sql it's trying to get Name by comparing NameLink.nameid = Name.id but name is null.

Comment: You are letting NHibernate to decide which JOIN to use. And it is INNER. You simply will need LEFT JOIN. Adjust your HQL generator, to be sure that you get the LEFT JOIN. Without that in place, you can use any kind of IS NOT NULL... but INNER JOIN will filter results anyhow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, what you need to use is left join, and this syntax will return what you'd expect

```
session
    .CreateQuery("select nl " +
                 " FROM NameLink nl " +
                 "  LEFT JOIN nl.Name n " +
                 " WHERE  n.DateModified > :xxx " + 
                 "    OR nl.DateModified > :xxx " 
    )
    .SetParameter("xxx", someDate)
    // some paging
    .SetMaxResults(2)
    // result just NameLink
    .List<NameLink>();
```

But in fact, this WHERE would work as well

```
" WHERE COALESCE(n.DateModified , nl.DateModified ) > :xxx "
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, this will definitely work. But, i was expecting that i may create fluent mapping using Join method. My GET query is going to webapi. And there we are using OData and manually create HQL query. So i'm using OData filter clause to add that DateModified comarison. I have edited my question.

Comment: In this case, Mapping is not relevant. Because mapped *relation* is responsible for JOIN itself, but QUERY (we) can effect if INNER or OUTER will be used. If you create HQL query manually, you can really use LEFT join. And that what you really should do. Hope it helps a bit ... I do use in my queries LEFT JOIN explicitly and almost always, because it is very standard, that our Domain model contains nullable references...

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow, sir! Enjoy amazing NHibernate ;)